# How to get user avatar via WPDB

Tags: wp-query, database, wpdb

For my REST-API i need to get for every post the username, date ... and Avatar !

```
$query ="SELECT POST.ID, POST.post_title, POST.post_date, 
USER.user_nicename FROM 
    wp0x_posts POST INNER JOIN wp0x_users USER 
ON USER.ID=POST.post_author and POST.post_type='post' ";
```

The probleme that i have faced is that the avatars are stored in wp_posts 
, so i don't know how to call it for posts titles and call it again for users avatars

it would be much easier if the avatars were stored in wp_users :/

is there a way to get all these values in one query

```
POST ID 
POST TITLE 
POST DATE
AUTHOR 
AVATAR
```

Comment: Avatars aren't stored in `wp_posts`, avatars in WordPress are URLs based on MD5 hashes of emails

Comment: What plugin are you using for custom avatars? As @tomJNowell says, avatars are URLs based on MD5 hashes of emails. The fact that you say the avatars are stored in wp_posts makes me think you are using a plugin that allows assigning custom avatars and stores them as custom post types.

Comment: yes , i 'am using WP User Avatar